# AAB file size increase after download from playstore. UNITY

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, android-app-bundle, build-settings

[image]I am facing an issue of increase in size when aab is downloaded from playstore. When I make an apk it is **360mbs** and aab file have size of **190mbs**. When I upload and download from store it is taking more than **1 gb** in storage. I have tried different compressions but it doesnot seems to work. I cannnot figure the issue will appreciate any help. Thanks

using Unity 2021.3.15f1 LTS.

I have tried all three compressions

- Default
- Lz4hc
- lz4
  Tried to make aab PAD method as well. I have attached screenshot of build settings.